# AWS Api gateway Developer portal doesn't show APis swagger

Tags: api, rest, aws-api-gateway

I have problem with AWS API Gateway Developer portal. Everything was up and running until we tried to do UI customization to the portal.
Now portal has those modifications on index.html. It shows everything else right, but when Api is selected from Api list Swagger and subscribe button isn't visible.
If I create new Api or a new Stage and deploy it to be subscribable I can see that API and its stages visible, but nothing more.

```
Inspection toos shows error: 
deep-extend.js:32 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at t (deep-extend.js:32:18)
    at deep-extend.js:132:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deep-extend.js:110:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.exports (deep-extend.js:104:7)
    at e.exports (swagger-ui.js:13846:44)
    at Apis.jsx:60:29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that this was a known issue:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-api-gateway-developer-portal/issues/594

Problem was that first time I dpleoyed with SAR and everything was fine. Next time I ran SAM deploy and Developer portal API List Broked.
After new deploy with SAR portal was fine.

This leaves us a maintenance problem if we can't use SAM script.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon API gateway is great. But the Amazon API developer portal isn't that extensible or full-featured. You may end up building your own. You might want to try some SaaS API Portals out there. One is apiable.io. it's bi-directionally integrated with Amazon API gateway so publishing existing APIs, bundling them as API products, or adding plans takes a few clicks.